# marginal function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

We have the following joint density

$$
f(x,y)= \frac{x}{2} \,\, for\,\, 0<xy<1 , 0<x<2\,\, and\,\, f(x,y)=0\,\,\, elsewhere
$$

I got the marginal $f(x)=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{x}{2} dx=\frac{1}{2}$, is it correct?

what about f(y)?

Comment: "what about f(y)?" Same approach?

Comment: I got $f(y)=x$ ... it is not normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct: $f_X(x)=1/2$ for $0<x<2$. To calculate $f_Y(y)$, we need to consider two cases: $0<y<1/2$ and $y\geq 1/2$.

Look at the area where the joint density is defined (the region upwards continues indefinitely).

[image]

If $0<y<1/2$, then 
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_0^2 \frac{x}2\,dx= 1.
$$
If $y\geq 1/2$, then 
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_0^{1/y} \frac{x}2\,dx= \frac{1}{4y^2}.
$$

Comment: may I ask which software you used to sketch and the code?

Comment: Oh, I'm very bad at using computer programs for drawing and just use copypast  from wolframalpha.